# How to issue a confirm (yes/no) message of a Android task?

Tags: xml, android, view, confirm

I want to ask the user if he agrees to continue launching a task, how do I issue a confirm window having Yes, No buttons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope this helps.
[Creating dialogs](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)