# remove line between custom option menu items

Tags: android

I customized the option menu, removed default background and customized the item it self by referring to a style, but I stack in removal the line between the items as shown in pic.

Any advice will be appreciated.

[image]

My code :

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:height="1dp" android:color="#B22222" /> 
   <solid android:color="#FCE6C9" /> 
     <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp"
          android:bottom="2dp" /> 
   <corners  android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"  android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="30dp"  android:topRightRadius="30dp" />

    </shape>
```

---

Option menu code :

```
  public class OptionMenu extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
    AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
    try {

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    // set the background drawable
    view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

    ((TextView) view).setTextSize(20); 

    // set the text color
    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);}
        });
    return view;}
     catch (InflateException e) { }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { }
            }
    return null; }
            });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);}


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.AboutUs:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.test.demo.ABOUT");
            startActivity(i);

             break;
                 case R.id.preferences:
                 Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.PREFS");
                 startActivity(p);
             break;
             case R.id.exit:
                   finish();
             break;}
            return false;} }
```

---

cool_menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:title="about"  android:id="@+id/AboutUs"  /> 
 <item android:title="Prefs"  android:id="@+id/preferences" /> 
 <item android:title="Exit"   android:id="@+id/exit" /> 
 </menu>
```

---

menu_style.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
        <style name="Theme_menu">
        <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/border</item> 
          </style>
     </resources>
```

---

referal of style in manifest to option menu :

```
  <activity
           android:name=".OptionMenu"
           android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme_menu">
```

Comment: have you tried giving width and height 0 dp for stroke ?

Comment: @Yogesh Somani this will not solve it , just remove the red border around each item , by the way thanks

Comment: Could you provide additional code? How do you initialize the options menu?

Answer (score 7):

As you mentioned you want to find a solution for removing line. I have no idea to do that but I also prefer to write my own menu system that is dynamic and customizable ( specially in animation and graphic ). You can pick the source code that written for my own projects.

And design your layout as you wish.

**Sample Result:**

[image]

**UPDATE: COMPLETE ANSWER**

**NEXT**

```
public class MenuActivity extends EnhancedActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

**NEXT**

```
public class EnhancedActivity extends Activity {

private static Activity _this;



public static Activity getCurrent() {
    return _this;
}



public static void setCurrent(Activity activity) {
    _this = activity;
}



@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    _this = this;

    G.gWidgetMenu.retarget();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (_this == this) {
        return;
    }

    _this = this;

    G.gWidgetMenu.retarget();
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    G.gWidgetMenu.forceClose();
    super.onPause();
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (G.gWidgetMenu.processKey(keycode, e)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
}
```

**NEXT**

```
public class G extends Application {

public static Context        gContext;
public static LayoutInflater gInflator;
public static WidgetMenu     gWidgetMenu;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    gContext = getApplicationContext();
    gInflator = (LayoutInflater) gContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    gWidgetMenu = new WidgetMenu();
}
}
```

**NEXT**

```
public class WidgetMenu extends FrameLayout implements AnimationListener {

private static final int       _RES_LAYOUT          = R.layout.widget_menu;
private static final int       _RES_ANIMATION_OPEN  = R.anim.anim_menu_open;
private static final int       _RES_ANIMATION_CLOSE = R.anim.anim_menu_close;

private static final Animation _ANIM_OPEN           = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(G.gContext, _RES_ANIMATION_OPEN);
private static final Animation _ANIM_CLOSE          = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(G.gContext, _RES_ANIMATION_CLOSE);

private static boolean         _canReceiveKey       = true;

private Ui                     _ui;



public WidgetMenu() {
    super(G.gContext);
    _ANIM_CLOSE.setAnimationListener(this);
    _ANIM_OPEN.setAnimationListener(this);

    View view = G.gInflator.inflate(_RES_LAYOUT, this);
    _ui = new Ui(view);
}



/**
 * open/close menu if menu key pressed, and close menu when back key
 * pressed. if this method act, it will return true other wise return false
 * as meaning no action occured.
 */
public boolean processKey(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    if ( !_canReceiveKey) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            if (getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                close();
            } else {
                open();
            }

            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                close();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
    }

    return false;
}



public void retarget() {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    if (EnhancedActivity.getCurrent() != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(this);
        }
        setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _ui.format();

        EnhancedActivity.getCurrent().addContentView(this, layoutParams);
        _canReceiveKey = true;
    }
}



public void forceClose() {
    onAnimationEnd(_ANIM_CLOSE);
}



/** play close animation and when close listener act, remove it from view */
private void close() {
    _canReceiveKey = false;
    startAnimation(_ANIM_CLOSE);
}



/** add control to view an show open animation */
private void open() {
    _canReceiveKey = false;
    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startAnimation(_ANIM_OPEN);
}



@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}



@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}



@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (animation == _ANIM_CLOSE) {
        setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    _canReceiveKey = true;
}



private class Ui {

    public ViewGroup panel_about;
    public ViewGroup panel_setting;



    public Ui(View view) {
        panel_about = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.panel_about);
        panel_setting = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.panel_setting);

        format();
    }



    public void format() {
        panel_about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i("LOG", "About Menu Pressed");
            }
        });

        panel_setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i("LOG", "Setting Menu Pressed");
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**NEXT** widget_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#c84300"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="4dip">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel_feedback"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="#330000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="4dip"
            android:paddingTop="4dip" android:layout_marginRight="2dip">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Feedback"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel_about"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="#330000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" android:layout_marginRight="2dip" android:paddingTop="4dip" android:paddingBottom="4dip">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_menu1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="About"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel_setting"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="#330000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip" android:paddingTop="4dip" android:paddingBottom="4dip" android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_menu2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NEXT** anim_menu_close.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

**NEXT** anim_menu_open.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

**NEXT** manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.uncocoder.menu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:name="com.uncocoder.menu.G"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.uncocoder.menu.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: would you please write full code including xml layout or other java class needed to complete the code project so i can test it completely thanks

Comment: i test it but how to set click listener so when click about button i will get about dialoge or feedback button or setting button , coz this is my first time to use animation java class , please , thanks

Comment: OK. I prepared two click listener for you in `format()` method of `Ui` so you can do anything in it's implementation. For example using `Intent intent = new Intent(EnhancedActivity.getCurrent(), AnotherActivity.class); EnhancedActivity.getCurrent().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Do you get your answer? please feedback here!

Comment: all answer provided here is an alternative solution to my post but you gave the best one till now man

Comment: would you please tell me how to implement ( about dialog or box ) to panel_about so when clicked about dialoge will show, thanks

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478517/how-to-display-a-yes-no-dialog-box-in-android . you can use `EnhancedActivity.getCurrent()` when reference to activity needs ( `this` )

Answer (score 2):

Those dividers look similar to those inserted by default between entries in a ListView. Depending on how similar Menu is to ListView (which is probably not very) the following code modification might work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent">

   <item android:title="about"  android:id="@+id/AboutUs"  /> 
   <item android:title="Prefs"  android:id="@+id/preferences" /> 
   <item android:title="Exit"   android:id="@+id/exit" /> 
</menu>
```

If that doesn't work it might be useful to read up on the [Menu object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html). I found the following quote from the `Menu.addIntentOptions()` function documentation.

> Normally this function will automatically remove any existing items in the menu in the same group and place a divider above and below the added items; this behavior can be modified with the flags parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem but I `cleared` problem instead of trying to solve it!I tried to show a `transparent` Activity with a layout `like` menu in it and when user click on menu button in main Activity,transparent Activity is shown.I hope these snippet codes help you:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) { 
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MyCustomMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

CustomMenuActivity:

```
public class MyCustomMenuActivity extends Activity {
    Button finishButton;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        finishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishbutton);
        finishButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyCustomMenuActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</LinearLayout>
```

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finishbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:background="@null"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="y.namespace"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MyCustomMenuActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

themetransparent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">    
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: good attempt but it not solve it as you said ,what i need real solution removing lines bettween option menu , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your Theme to AppTheme to AppTheme.NoActionBar.

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```