# What's the simplest code to make a dialog box with just text and OK/Cancel buttons on Android 4?

Tags: java, android

Using Android API 14 or higher, what is the easiest way to make a dialog box? All I want is a few lines of text, OK button, and Cancel button. The Cancel button closes the dialog, the OK button performs some method that I have.

The reason I ask is because I'm going through a few different tutorial books and many of them seem to make dialog creation an overly complicated process. So I want the absolute simplest way to do this (fewest lines of code).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478517/how-to-display-a-yes-no-dialog-box-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is use a DialogFragment but if you want the fewest lines of code then the below code will work just fine:

```
public void showMessageDialog(Context context, int message, int title) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle(title)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO: Ok click stuff
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
    .show();
}
```

The variables `message` and `title` are both String resource identifiers.