# Adding small subviews to main view on Android

Tags: android, modal-dialog

I'd like to make something close to alerts or modal view in iOS (message and 1 or 2 or 3 buttons), but on Android. For example, then users clicks Back button on some screens of the app he will asked to save or not his progress.
Are there any native ways to do it using Android SDK in Eclipse?
Any suggestions how to implement it in custom design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this site](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) and [this site](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) is giving a simple custom dialog example in code. you can use the code as guidance.

Comment: you can also use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478517/how-to-display-a-yes-no-dialog-box-in-android) to create simple yes/no dialog