# Android AlertDialog Move PositiveButton to the right and NegativeButton on the left

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm new with android.

Currently I want to show an `AlertDialog` box with 'OK' & 'Cancel' buttons.

The default is PositiveButton: Left, NegativeButton: Right

Can you let me know how can I move the PositiveButton to the right side & NegativeButton to the left side?

Is there any chance/trouble if Negativebutton cause a bad sound when pressing OK, if We change text "OK" to NegativeButton & "Cancel" to PositiveButton.

My Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SUtils.getContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Confirmation?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //Todo
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //TOdo
                        }
                    })

dialog = builder.create();
```

Thanks,
Angel

Answer (score 39):

This might not be a direct answer. But just some information on related topic. From [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24138) thread in Google's own forum, Romain guy said..

> Going forward the order of positive/negative buttons will be the one
>   used in ICS.

and the convention per OS version is

- On devices prior to Honeycomb, the button order (left to right) was
  POSITIVE - NEUTRAL - NEGATIVE.
- On newer devices using the Holo theme, the button order (left to
  right) is now NEGATIVE - NEUTRAL - POSITIVE.

If it is a convention, that android/Google wants to follow, isn't it better you follow the same, since your users won't be using your app alone. After all user friendliness is the first thing a developer looks for..

Comment: That's the only correct and helpful answer since those workarounds posted above don't fix the problem for api 11 and above users, it just causes confusion ;] ...

Answer (score 3):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SUtils.getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Confirmation?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //TOdo
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //TOdo
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })


                diaglog = builder.create();
```

But I recommend to go along with the convention unless you have a good reason to change the order. That will make easier for users to use your application.

Comment: Is there any chance/trouble if Negativebutton cause a bad sound when pressing OK, if We change text "OK" to NegativeButton & "Cancel" to PositiveButton.

Comment: It is possible but I have never seen such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way to shift the buttons of the `AlertDialog` to the right hand side is to hide the `leftSpacer`, a `LinearLayout` within the core XML which handles the default layout.

```
// Fetch the PositiveButton
final Button       lPositiveButton = lDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
// Fetch the LinearLayout.
final LinearLayout lParent         = (LinearLayout) lPositiveButton.getParent();
// Ensure the Parent of the Buttons aligns it's contents to the right.
lParent.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
// Hide the LeftSpacer. (Strict dependence on the order of the layout!)
lParent.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant of ways but it will do what you want

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SUtils.getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Confirmation?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //TOdo
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //TOdo
                    }
                })


            diaglog = builder.create();
```

Just make the `Cancel` button as positive and the `Ok` button as negative.

Comment: Is there any chance/trouble if Negativebutton cause a bad sound when pressing OK, if We change text "OK" to NegativeButton & "Cancel" to PositiveButton.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the diffault setting in android
But you can change the text ok to cancle 
set the functionally accroding this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SUtils.getContext());
    builder.setMessage("Confirmation?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setNegativeButton("OK", 
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //TOdo
                        }
                   })
           .setPositiveButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //TOdo
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });


dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: Is there any chance/trouble if Negativebutton cause a bad sound when pressing OK, if I changing like this

Comment: no chance of trouble.I am use this type in my android application

Answer (score 0):

check this https://github.com/hslls/order-alert-buttons

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.hslls:order-alert-buttons:1.0.0'
}


AlertDialogParams params = new AlertDialogParams();
params.mTitle = "title";
params.mMessage = "message";
params.mPositiveText = "Ok";
params.mNegativeText = "Cancel";
params.mCancelable = true;
params.mAlign = BUTTON_ALIGN.POSITIVE_BUTTON_LEFT;  // fix button position
params.mClickListener = new AlertDialogClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPositiveClicked() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeClicked() {

    }
};

AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialogBuilder.createAlertDialog(this, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that there is a space layout between the `neutral button` and `-ve/+ve buttons` with the place "1" in the `buttonBarLayout` in which the buttons.

So, at first we need to remove that space and or make it's visibility `GONE` (`invisible` will let it still takes a space in the `buttonBarLayout`) also we better to use method onShowListner better that doing that after showing the dialog by:

```
 alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button neutralButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) neutralButtonOrAnyOtherBtnFromThe3Btns.getParent();
            Space space= (Space) view.getChildAt(1);
        }
 });
```

then the rest is your design, wish that helps