# Alert Dialog Switch Buttons Positions Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I cannot figure out why the "Close" button is showing 1st on the left and the "Help Translate" button on the right.

[image]

I want the "Help Translate" button on the left and "Close" on the right

```
case R.id.action_translate:
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.translate_text));
            builder.setPositiveButton ("Help Translate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Close", null);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
```

Comment: just some information on related [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644448/android-alertdialog-move-positivebutton-to-the-right-and-negativebutton-on-the-l)

Answer (score 1):

> I want the "Help Translate" button on the left and Close on the right

you shouldn't really do it. The order is decided by the operating system in this case. In the up to gingerbread, the order was *positive-neutral-negative*, starting from honeycomb the order is *negative-neutral-positive*. Even though you couldn't like it, it is consistent with the way the operating system works, and in the aim to give the user the same UX across the applications, you shouldn't change it

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.action_translate:
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.translate_text));
        builder.setNegativeButton("Help Translate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                });
        builder.setPositiveButton ("Close", null);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        return true;
```

Actually its the android standard!! if you dont want to follow it then you can use this trick :)