# Where could I find information on creating a question popup?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Hey guys beginner in android studio here, basically my book rental is up and I am not sure of the name for something. In the tool bar of my fragment, I have a way to delete that fragment from the recyclerView. Everything works but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of making a menu that pops up asking "are you sure you want to delete this?". I am almost positive I have seen it on here before as an example but I just cant seem to find it, probably because I am not entering the right search terms. Thanks for your time everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a Yes/No dialog box on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478517/how-to-display-a-yes-no-dialog-box-on-android)

Comment: That duplicate answer is a bit old.  You still use AlertDialog, but you wrap it in a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to add a Dialog.

I would check out the documentation here.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs