# execute functions one by one

Tags: java, function

I want to know how to execute any function completely before moving to next coding statements.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnBack:
        i = new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.btnOne:
        showDisclaimerDialog();
        Log.d("agreed value", agreed+"");
        if (agreed) {
            Log.e("Inside", "btnOne");
            appObj.setMaxFeeds(1);
            i = new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, SelectFeedsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btnTwo:
        showDisclaimerDialog();
        if(agreed) {
            appObj.setMaxFeeds(2);
            i = new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, SelectFeedsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btnFive:
        showDisclaimerDialog();
        if (agreed) {
            appObj.setMaxFeeds(5);
            i = new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, SelectFeedsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }


private void showDisclaimerDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            SetUpActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Disclaimer");
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.disclaimer)));
    builder.setPositiveButton("I Agree",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    agreed = true;
                    Log.e("Inside I agree",agreed+"");
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    agreed = false;
                    Log.e("Inside Cancel",agreed+"");
                }
            });

    builder.create().show();
    agreed=false;
    Log.e("Inside dialog",agreed+"");

}
```

When I click on "btnOne" , the control of the execution should go to "showDiclaimerDialog()" without executing further statments which are

```
        Log.d("agreed value", agreed+"");
    if (agreed) {
        Log.e("Inside", "btnOne");
        appObj.setMaxFeeds(1);
        i = new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, SelectFeedsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: Remove or comment that code block in your `R.id.btnOne` case. If this is not the case, explain further what you want/need.

Comment: Just put this piece of code in the onClick of the Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't(as in you can but really really really shouldn't) block execution in the GUI thread. See this question for details.

[Dialogs / AlertDialogs: How to "block execution" while dialog is up (.NET-style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot for the suggestions but is there any way to execute multiple functions but only one after another?because I require the solution in another part of code also.I want to call two functions one by one.like  first();  second();

Comment: Yep, like Michael Laffargue said. Put it in the onClick of the dialog instead.