# How to make Alert, Prompt and confirm dialog of javascript in java Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, native-code

I want to make a confirm function in java just like a alert in `javascript`.

**Example javascript code:**
          `var a = prompt("");`

In java i have a function that returns a string with a dialog box input;

```
      public static boolean log ;
      public String value;
        public String androidPrompt(){
              log = true;             
              showMyDialog();
              while(log){
              }
              return value;

        }


       public void showMyDialog(){
          log= false;
           value = //inputed value from dialog; 
       }
```

But my application don't respond. What should i do. I want to pause 
`androidPrompt()` while `showMyDialog()` is not done. and when `showMyDialog()` 
is done `androidPrompt()` function will resume and return the value

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style)

Comment: If your function call is from __WebView__, then you must create a __JavaScript Interface__; if not, then just read about accepted prompts / dialogs as allowed by Android. Also, all JS codes may not respond unless the interface is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example javascript code: var a = prompt("");

Android does not support that sort of blocking UI call. Instead, use listeners to notify something within your app when the user has accepted the dialog (e.g., pressed the OK button).

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear about where the call is being invoked. If you want to execute Java (android) functions in JavaScript, then you must create an Interface.

Here is an example of emulating an **alert()** function using an Interface.

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    Context mContext;
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    
    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    
}

//at the oncreate of your activity where webviews is being created 
WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.sidmyWebView);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android"); //this name will be used in JS
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.clearCache(true);     //temporary for css reload
WebSettings myWebSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
myWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   //this enables js on this page

//now, in JS file execution, you can emulate the js alert function as 
//alert("Show toast");  //this will not show anything, as you noted
Android.showToast("Calling Alert-show in Android WebView - Java/JavaScript");   //this will work
```

But if your requirement is simply the normal alerts/dialogues, then read on acceptable non-obstructive methods allowed by Android.