# modal dialog in Android

Tags: android, modal-dialog

I need to create a modal dialog in Android. By modal, I mean the code should stop executing and wait for the dialog to close. When I tried AlertDialog or PopupWindow, the code always continues without waiting.

Comment: what code always continues? Did you start something in a background thread? When you pop the dialog, stop that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will find your answer here

[Dialogs / AlertDialogs: How to "block execution" while dialog is up (.NET-style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style)

In general you should not be blocking the code while a dialog is visible, your logic should be different and fit android way of doing things.